# Xero API connection - Redirect URI parameters

Tags: oauth, xero-api

When authorising a xero API connection, is there a way to pass parameters to the redirect URI so they are passed back so that i can identify the client or other information in the redirect back?

https://localhost:44367/integrations/xeroconnect?&clientId={ID}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the "state" parameter, to pass a number of (comma-separated) values, which I explode() on arrival to the redirect URI, to authenticate call caller and do other stuff. It is mentioned here: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/auth-flow

Comment: thanks for the idea, I ended up just using the routing I had and dealing with it other ways but would be good if you could pass them additional params. Thanks. Actually I may have used local cookie data for those requests, it was a while ago now lol